# Reading .hex file in VHDL

Tags: file-io, vhdl

I'm trying to read an intel .hex file using the following VHDL code snippet. My synthesizer is having a problem with the part of the code that is supposed to check for and discard the ':' character at the start of a line. The synthesis tool gives this error "Call to procedure without body" (line marked with comment). I have never seen this error and don't know what it means. Is there a solution for this error (or an alternate way to discard the ':' character)?

```
function Load_Data(constant x: in integer) return ROM_Data is
    use std.textio.all;
    use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;

    file ROMFILE: TEXT open READ_MODE is "IIU_Code.hex";

    variable newline: line;
    variable newchar: character;
    variable newbyte: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    variable newword: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

    variable NextAddr, ByteCount: integer;
    variable NewROM: ROM_Data := (others => (others => '0'));
    variable valid: boolean := True;
begin
    while (valid) loop
        readline(ROMFILE, newline);
        read(newline,newchar,valid);                      --ERROR HERE!!!
        if (newchar = ':') and (valid = True) then
            hread(newline,newbyte);
            ByteCount := to_integer(unsigned(newbyte));
            hread(newline,newword);
            NextAddr := to_integer(unsigned(newword));
            hread(newline,newbyte);
            if newbyte = X"01" then     --check for EOF marker
                valid := False;
            end if;
            for i in 1 to ByteCount loop
                hread(newline,newbyte);
                NewROM(NextAddr) := newbyte;
                NextAddr := NextAddr + 1;
            end loop;
        end if;
    end loop;

    file_close(ROMFILE);
    return NewROM;
end;
```

Comment: The declaration for type ROM_data isn't in evidence but more interestingly why do you have an expectation that file operations are synthesis eligible?  Generally only three object classes have any meaning in synthesis (constants, signals and variables (can include shared variables)). E.g. See IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (withdrawn) 8.1.1.2 Entity declarative part "ignored: — file_declaration", 8.2 Subprograms and packages, 8.2.1.1 Formal parameters "c) File parameters  File parameters shall not be supported."

Comment: I'm using it to load a constant from a file at compile time. The goal is to make a prom out of logic gates. It's a silly goal, but I don't make the goals, I just do what I'm told. ROM - DATA is an array of std-logic-vector(7dt0)

Comment: This - [Initializing a ram from file-- problem??](http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/initializing-a-ram-from-file-problem.651103/ "Initializing a ram from file-- problem??") which also shows up in a Xilinx forum indicates you are indeed trying to synthesize and that the message is likely from Synplify. read is definitely a procedure, It would seem between your case and Daniel's that the read procedure isn't implemented in Synplify, a cheap way of rendering file operations moot by semantic error. There's more than one way to get your ROM data in besides file operations.

Comment: It seems to be only upset about the read() procedure that returns a char. When I comment that one out, none of the other reads cause an error. I'm not sure why that one in particular is a problem, but perhaps I can discard the leading :'s from the file in some other way...

Comment: Your synthesis tool doesn't have a procedure body for read in it's library.  A shortcoming that prevents you from using it and one you can't overcome.  The intention is to prevent file read programmatically.  Xilinx has their own way of loading ROM images, I believe Altera recently implemented something recently, too.  They aren't VHDL language constructs (but may show up as attributes and/or generic declarations and required packages).  The read procedure is implementation dependent for the host system.  What host system does your FPGA, etc. have?

Comment: This is for a Microsemi ProASIC3. It uses Synplify Pro for synthesis. Microsemi unfortunately doesn't have an adequate IP for a ROM that they provide.

Answer (score 1):

In lieu of trying to force synthesis to initialize ROM from a file I've been known to write C programs that convert data for models to constants, in this case by generating entity/architecture pairs:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_VECTOR 512

void rom_header (rom_name,array_size)
char *rom_name;
int array_size;
{
    printf("library ieee;\nuse ieee.std_logic_1164.all;\n");
    printf("\nentity %s is\n    port (\n",rom_name);
    printf("\tindex:\t\tin     integer range 0 to %d;\n",array_size*8-1);
    printf("\tOE:\t\tin     std_logic;\n");
    printf("\toutput:\t\tout    std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)\n");
    printf("    );\nend ;\n");
    printf("\narchitecture behave of %s is\n\n",rom_name);
    printf("    subtype bytestring is bit_vector( 7 downto 0);\n");
    printf("    type bytestream is array (0 to %d) of bytestring;\n\n",
        array_size*8-1);
    printf("    constant byte_array:\tbytestream := (\n\t    ");
}

void rom_tail() {
    printf("    begin\n\n");
    printf("    output <= To_StdLogicVector(byte_array(index)) ");
    printf("when OE = '1' else\n");
    printf("              (others => 'Z')                      ");
    printf("when OE = '0' else\n");
    printf("              (others => 'X');\n");
    printf("\n\nend behave;\n\n");
}

int main (argc,argv) 
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
extern char *optarg;
extern int optind, opterr;
extern int getopt();

char *infile;
char key_vector[MAX_VECTOR][16];
char plain_vector[MAX_VECTOR][16];
char cipher_vector[MAX_VECTOR][16];
char testinput[2047];
char testkey[17];
char testplain[17];
char testcipher[17];

int encrypt[MAX_VECTOR];
int i;
int len;
int testcount = 0;
int totalcount = 0;
int linenumber = 0;
int vector = 0;
int encode = 1;

    while ( (i=getopt(argc,argv,"i:")) != -1 )  {
        switch (i) {
        case 'i':
            infile = optarg;
            if((freopen(optarg,"r",stdin)) == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr,"ERROR:%s, can't open %s for input\n",
                        argv[0],optarg);
                exit(-1);
            }
        break;
        case '?':
            fprintf(stderr,"usage: %s [-i infile] \n",argv[0]);
            fprintf(stderr,"\ngenerates VHDL arrays for DES test vectors:\n");
            fprintf(stderr,"\tcipher_vector.vhdl\n");
            fprintf(stderr,"\tencrypt_vector.vhdl\n");
            fprintf(stderr,"\tkey_vector.vhdl\n");
            fprintf(stderr,"\tplain_vector.vhdl\n");
            exit (-1);
        break;
        }
    }

    while (fgets(testinput,(sizeof testinput) -1, stdin) != NULL ) {

    linenumber++;
    if ( strncmp(testinput,"encrypt",7) == 0) { /* mode = encode */
        encode = 1;
            fprintf(stderr,"%s",testinput);
       }
        else
        if ( strncmp(testinput,"decrypt",7) == 0) { /* mode = decode */
            fprintf(stderr,"%s",testinput);
        encode = 0;
        }
        else 
        if ( strncmp(testinput," ",1) == 0) { /* key, plain & cipher */
        testcount++;
            len = sscanf(testinput,"%s%s%s*", testkey, testplain, testcipher);
            if (len != 3) {
                fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: %s, wrong vector count, line %d\n",
                    argv[0], linenumber);
                exit(-1);
            }
            else if (strlen(testkey) != 16) {
                fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: %s wrong byte count testkey, line %d\n",
                    argv[0],linenumber);
                exit(-1);
        }
            else if (strlen(testplain) != 16) {
                fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: %s wrong byte count testplain, line %d\n",
                    argv[0],linenumber);
                exit(-1);
            }
            else if (strlen(testcipher) != 16) {
                fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: %s wrong byte count testcipher, line %d\n",
                    argv[0],linenumber);
                exit(-1);
            }
            else {
                encrypt[vector] = encode;
                strncpy(   key_vector[vector],   testkey,16);
                strncpy( plain_vector[vector], testplain,16);
                strncpy(cipher_vector[vector],testcipher,16);

                for ( i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                    if ( !isxdigit(key_vector[vector][i]) ||
                         !isxdigit(plain_vector[vector][i]) ||
                         !isxdigit(cipher_vector[vector][i]) ) {
                    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: %s, Vector: %d contains nonhex\n",
                        argv[0], vector+1);
                    fprintf(stderr,"\t%s\n",testinput);
                        exit(-1);
                    }
                }
            }
            vector++;
            if (vector == MAX_VECTOR) {
                fprintf(stderr,"%s: Maximum number of vectors = %d\n",
                    argv[0],MAX_VECTOR);
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    else {                                /* nothing but eyewash */
            if ( testcount ) {
        fprintf(stderr," %d test vectors\n",testcount);
                totalcount +=testcount;
                testcount = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    fprintf(stderr," Total: %d test vectors\n",totalcount);

    if (freopen("key_vector.vhdl","w",stdout) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: %s can write to key_vector.vhdl\n",argv[0]);
        exit (-1);
    } 
    rom_header("key_vector",totalcount);
    for(vector = 0; vector < totalcount; vector++) {

        for ( i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
            if ( !(i & 1)) {
                printf("x\"%c",key_vector[vector][i]);
            }
            else {
                if ( i < 15) {
                    printf("%c\",",key_vector[vector][i]);
                }
                else {
                    printf("%c\"",key_vector[vector][i]); // no comma
                }
            } 
        }
        if (vector != totalcount-1) 
            printf(",\n\t    ");
        else
            printf("\n\t);\n");
    }    
    rom_tail();

    if (freopen("plain_vector.vhdl","w",stdout) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: %s can write to plain_vector.vhdl\n",argv[0]);
        exit (-1);
    } 
    rom_header("plain_vector",totalcount);
    for(vector = 0; vector < totalcount; vector++) {

        for ( i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
            if ( !(i & 1)) {
                printf("x\"%c",plain_vector[vector][i]);
            }
            else {
                if ( i < 15) {
                    printf("%c\",",plain_vector[vector][i]);
                }
                else {
                    printf("%c\"",plain_vector[vector][i]); // no comma
                }
            } 
        }
        if (vector != totalcount-1) 
            printf(",\n\t    ");
        else
            printf("\n\t);\n");
    }    
    rom_tail();

    if (freopen("cipher_vector.vhdl","w",stdout) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: %s can write to cipher_vector.vhdl\n",argv[0]);
        exit (-1);
    } 
    rom_header("cipher_vector",totalcount);
    for(vector = 0; vector < totalcount; vector++) {

        for ( i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
            if ( !(i & 1)) {
                printf("x\"%c",cipher_vector[vector][i]);
            }
            else {
                if ( i < 15) {
                    printf("%c\",",cipher_vector[vector][i]);
                }
                else {
                    printf("%c\"",cipher_vector[vector][i]); // no comma
                }
            } 
        }
        if (vector != totalcount-1) 
            printf(",\n\t    ");
        else
            printf("\n\t);\n");
    }    
    rom_tail();

    if (freopen("encrypt_vector.vhdl","w",stdout) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: %s can write to encrypt_vector.vhdl\n",argv[0]);
        exit (-1);
    } 
    printf("library ieee;\nuse ieee.std_logic_1164.all;\n");
    printf("\nentity encrypt_vector is\n    port (\n");
    printf("\tindex:\t\tin     integer range 0 to %d;\n",totalcount-1);
    printf("\toutput:\t\tout    std_logic\n");
    printf("    );\nend ;\n");
    printf("\narchitecture behave of encrypt_vector is\n\n");
    printf("    constant bit_array:\tstd_logic_vector(0 to %d) := (\n\t    ",
            totalcount-1);

    i = 0;
    for(vector = 0; vector < totalcount; vector++) {
    printf("'%1d'",encrypt[vector]);i++;
    if ((i == 16) && (vector != totalcount-1)) {
        printf(",\n\t    ");
        i = 0;
    }
    else if (vector == totalcount-1)
        printf("\n\t);\n");
    else
        printf(",");
    }    
    printf("    begin\n\n");
    printf("    output <= bit_array(index);");
    printf("\n\nend behave;\n\n");

    exit (0);
}
```

You could also do this for packages or even subprograms.

This particular conversion software uses a  form of valid vectors preceded by an encryption mode switch and having a first column space, providing hex values of the right string length:

`#
encrypt
#
 0101010101010101 95F8A5E5DD31D900 8000000000000000
 0101010101010101 DD7F121CA5015619 4000000000000000
 0101010101010101 2E8653104F3834EA 2000000000000000
 0101010101010101 4BD388FF6CD81D4F 1000000000000000
 0101010101010101 20B9E767B2FB1456 0800000000000000
 0101010101010101 55579380D77138EF 0400000000000000
 0101010101010101 6CC5DEFAAF04512F 0200000000000000
#`

It's the test vectors for a byte wide interfaced DES chip, and in this case only used in a test bench.  There's nothing stopping you from embedding something like you want.

This little C program is quite old but I believe I updated it recently enough it would compile and run, it spits out several different 'vector' files for the test bench based on what the values are used for.  It wants the input file to be concluded with a comment line ('#' in the first column), followed by a newline.

So the message here is don't count directly on your synthesis tools to initialize data (unless they handle it with explicitly supported routines).

See [How to synthesis a rom and load initial data into it ?](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/How-to-synthesis-a-rom-and-load-initial-data-into-it/td-p/444276), for a hint thread in Xilinx, otherwise noting you haven't specified target platform.

**addendum**

The questioner has been forthcoming with additional information in comments, wherein automated software has exhorted us to **Please avoid extended discussions in comments**.

The target is a Microsemi ProASIC3, which also prompted another look  at the provided Load_Data function, whose input argument `x` doesn't show up in the function body.  While that indicates the author may have been battling uphill restrictions  trying to read a file.

Looking at Microsemi's web site we see that a ProASIC3 can have an embedded 1K bit FLASHROM, which may or may not be the ROM in question.  I'm an ASIC designer from way back and can appreciate the size range of these devices, intended for among other uses System on Chip applications.  You'd expect the vendor would be able to supply information on how to use the FLASHROM.

For other ROM purposes in lieu of vendor supplied method of loading ROM it would seem that creating a synthesis compatible method of embedding an array of constants is in order (analogous to what's shown in the C programming example).

One characteristic of Read Only Memory in programmable devices is that the values are typically included as part of device programming.